# Add doesn't work on C# Xaml

Tags: c#, dictionary, addition

I have a problem I don't understand. I had a List in my xaml code, and I select an Item. Then, I want to add it in the list of the User. So I do in code Behind:

`(DataContext as Personnage).Inv.AjouterObj(1,(AjouterObjInv.obj as Objet));`

That works.

Then, let's go in my inventaire Inv, AjouterObj look like :

```
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public Dictionary<Objet, int> MonInventaire { get; set; } 

    public Inventaire()
    {
        MonInventaire  = new Dictionary<Objet, int>();

    }
    public void AjouterObj(int nb, Objet obj)
    {

        if (MonInventaire.Count==0)
        {

            MonInventaire.Add(new Objet(obj.Nom, obj.Description), 1);
            return;
        }

        if (MonInventaire.ContainsKey(obj))
        {

            MonInventaire[obj] = MonInventaire[obj] + nb;

        }
        else {
            MonInventaire.Add(obj, nb);
        }
```

But when I do it in Step by step, after the Adding, MonInventaire.Count() Is always equal to 0, the add did not work!

Comment: You did not really debug your code step-by-step, i would say... Set a breakpoint at all occurrences of the MonInventaire.Add method, and run your program. Is the breakpoint hitting?

Comment: Thank for the answer ! So.. What should I use to add to my dictionary?

Comment: (Just ignore what i said about Add. It was wrong. I was distracted for a moment, and then somehow thought about List<T> while writing about Dictionary. It was just a brain fart...)

Comment: And that very strange, because I do that with an other class and it work o.o

Comment: All i can say is that you did not debug properly. Somewhere, somehow - although i cannot tell where - you got confused. Either the Add method was not executed (contrary to what you believe), or you did not really debug step-by-step. Is the Objet constructor perhaps throwing an exception? If you made sure that Add was *really* executed and count is still zero, pay attention to whether your program executes code that could potentially remove elements from the dictionary again...

Comment: Yes, the break point hitting. During the `if (MonInventaire.Count()==0)` I have : "MonInventaire : Count =0", "nb" and "obj" was good, and after the adding I have "MonInventaire : Count=0" and the same for nb and obj..

Comment: You need to debug more thoroughly. That you believe that Add was executed while the Dictionary Count still remains zero should tell you that you did not really debug thoroughly. The code in your question does not reveal anything with regard to either a code error or to a possible mistake in your thinking/debugging...

Comment: Also, i removed the WPF and XAML tags from your question. Your problem is not about XAML nor WPF, but about a bog-standard dictionary, right?

Comment: Yes Maybe, You're right !
 
Ohh So I really don't understand where the problem can come from x.x Because I did something similar and it work :
`public Dictionary <string,int> caracteristique { get; set; }`
`public void ajouterCarac(string nom, int carac)
        {
           
            if (caracteristique.Count() == 0)
            {
                caracteristique.Add(nom, carac);
                return;
            }`

Comment: Maybe It come From my Classe Objet... I don't understand why, but I can check..

Comment: is the `Objet` a custom class? If so, can you check if any exception is being thrown from this line `new Objet(obj.Nom, obj.Description)`? also can you try creating the `Object` using `new Objet(obj.Nom, obj.Description)` before directly adding to dictionary?

Comment: Yes, Objet is a custom classe
`public class Objet
    {


        [DataMember]

        public string Nom { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        //[DataMember]
        //private Caracteristique carac { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string SrcImg { get; set; }

        public Objet(string nom, string description)
        {
            this.Nom = nom;
            this.Description = description;

        }

 public Objet(Objet ob)
        {
this.Nom = ob.Nom;
this.Description = ob.Description;}`

Comment: And I don't see any exception..